# Not able to selected defined file type in showOpenDialog in Brackets API

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am using the Brackets API for selecting my JSON file but I can't choose any type of .extension.

The code is given below.

```
NativeFileSystem.showOpenDialog(false, false, "Please Selected ADHeaderConfig.json",'',[".json"],callback, callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5th argument `fileTypes`, which specifies a file extension filter, isn't truly supported yet -- it works on Mac, but not on Windows or Linux. (Unfortunately this isn't very well documented; I'll see about improving that).

There's a [Brackets backlog item tracking this](https://trello.com/c/430aXkpq/488-showopendialog-improvements), which you can upvote. There's also [commented-out code in brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/appshell/appshell_extensions_win.cpp#L491) that gives a head start on the Windows implementation, if you (or anyone else) would like to give it a shot and submit a pull request.